# MS-Excel Array Formula Problem : How do you get all the value in an array except the last one?

Tags: excel

Now that I have found the way to make an array of dates from a date range (Ex. 12-08-19 to 17-08-19) using the following formula:

cell c2 : `01-10-18`

cell d2 : `03-10-18`

cell e2 : `{=ROW(INDIRECT(C2&":"&D2))}`

Result : `{43374;43375;43376}`

However, I need to get all the date from this array except the last one - then make it split out those day and put them under the column or row and later count for how many ; let say ; 01-10-18 in case that I have lots of date ranges containing 01-10-18.

In addition - each date range comes with created date - and I also want to assign the create date to those value as well so later I can accuulate numbers of Ex. 01-10-18 and compare between 2 created date for how many 01-10-18 has increased between a certain created date range.

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Comment: Sounds like you really want a Pivot Table with filters

Comment: Hi Mr. Craner - thank you for your comment , let me ask if pivot table has the ability to spill array element out of it ? Could you let me know how ? Thank you in advance.